# Bokeh mutliple diagramms in one html file

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I know that I can create a single HTML page for every diagram, but is it possible that I can show 2 or 3 Bokeh diagramms at one HTML page? I have already looked on the Internet but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, just use one of the layout primitives documented at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for@Eugene Pakhomov